# Rubular Expression

Tags: regex, rubular

How can we extract the words from a string in rubular expression?

```
$0Public$robotics00$india0$000facebook
```

If we want to extract the words `Public robotics india facebook` from the above string, how can we?

I am using `([^0$])`, but it is giving the letters not the proper words.

Comment: Use a quantifier like `+` to continue matching.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match `$` followed by optional zeroes, and use a capture group to match the characters other than `$` `0` or a whitespace char

```
\$0*([^0$\s]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\$` Match a `$` char
- `0*` Match optional zeroes
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^0$\s]+` Match 1+ times any char except `0` `$` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/QmnBasOk7jOFrr)

```
re = /\$0*([^0$\s]+)/
str = '$0Public$robotics00$india0$000facebook
'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.first
end
```

Output

```
Public
robotics
india
facebook
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try a regex split here:

```rb
input = "$0Public$robotics00$india0$000facebook"
parts = input.split(/\d*\$\d*/)
puts parts
```

This prints:

```
Public
robotics
india
facebook
```